# How to integrate ccavenue in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to integrate cc-avenue in Magento 1.9.2.4, but I'm not able to do that. Is there any free module available or any other way to integrate cc-avenue?

Comment: contact cc-avenue team, they will give module.

Comment: I tried with magento_ccavenueMCPG_payment_module
but got this error..
Site error: the file /home/ltfab/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Ccavenuepay/Model/Observer.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.

Comment: oh, than you need ioncube_loader to be installed in server to work this extension. but i dont recommend to use extension that needs ioncube_encoder. instead of this did you contacted official cc avenue team ?

Comment: ok, will try to contact with them. Thanks for response.

Comment: thats better, let me know once you get the solution.

Comment: We won't do the development for you, so if you need help with something, this question is lacking some code. And if you are just looking for an  existing module [StackOverlfow is not the right place](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In the later case, http://magento.stackexchange.com, is the suited place for that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Asking for extensions is explicitly off-topic. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the files provided by the vendors in the Magento directory, enable it from the backend, and add Merchant Id, Encryption Key, and Access Code details.

It should then work.